# .NET WinForms DataBinding - BindingList<IBindableItem> where some implementations of IBindableItem may also implement IList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, recursive-databinding

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266902/net-databinding-custom-datasource-for-a-recursive-tree-of-folders-and-items) of mine, and unfortunately I'm having a difficult time summarizing the issue in my Title--so please bear with me.

I've created a databindable class called `Folder` which implements a `ITreeItem` interface and inherits from `BindingList<ITreeItem>`.  I have a second class, `TreeLeaf`, which is a leaf in the tree, a terminus that can't contain more child items.

The intent is to be able to databind to a `Folder` and have databinding walk the tree of folders (and n-level subfolders) and leafs.  The databinding, however, doesn't descend into the underlying BindingList of a `Folder`, and as a result the `Folder` is appearing to not have child items when databound.

So far it looks like databinding is working with the folder as an instace of `ITreeItem`, which is correct, and not realizing that the `Folder` is anything other than an instance of `ITreeItem`.

**My question is**: how can I either expose to databinding that a folder is *both* an implementation of `ITreeItem` and also a descendant of `BindingList<ITreeItem>`; or how can I hook into the databinding to help it walk down the structure?

Here is a sample of the implementation so far:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeData
{
    public interface ITreeItem
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class TreeLeaf : ITreeItem
    {
        public TreeLeaf(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Folder : BindingList<ITreeItem>, ITreeItem
    {
        public Folder(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Example
    {
        public Example()
        {
            var rootFolder = new Folder("Root");
            var subFolder1 = new Folder("Folder1");
            var subFolder2 = new Folder("Folder2");

            rootFolder.Add(subFolder1);
            rootFolder.Add(subFolder2);

            subFolder1.Add(new TreeLeaf("Item1"));
            subFolder1.Add(new TreeLeaf("Item2"));

            subFolder2.Add(new TreeLeaf("Item3"));
            subFolder2.Add(new TreeLeaf("Item4"));

            var treeDataSource = new BindingSource();
            treeDataSource.DataSource = rootFolder;

            // For my purposes the 'bindableControl' is
            // an Infragistics UltraTree or UltraGrid.
            //bindableControl.DataSource = treeDataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider having a Children property instead?

```
public class Folder : ITreeItem
{
    public Folder(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new BindingList<ITreeItem>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BindingList<ITreeItem> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I ended up having to do something along these lines, basically adding an "Items" property of IBindingList to the base-class.  Not quite what I was hoping for, but good enough for now.